# Problem with AMD HD 8xxx Series graphics card

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, 64-bit, radeon

I bought a `Dell inspiron 17R 5721` it has 2 graphics cards, an `Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000` and a `AMD Radeon HD 8730M`. Intel's card (on board) works just fine after doing what it says in [this article](http://www.techlw.com/2012/08/install-latest-intel-gpu-drivers-in.html).

With AMD's card, no such luck. I've tried to install the catalyst drivers that `ubuntu` suggests but no luck. I checked on AMD's website for drivers, it's in version 13.04 for about a month and some now, and that version, doesn't list my card as supported.

Does anyone know if I can make my graphics card work with ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nope, I never found that one. I'm gonna give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Please provide info about the application and if you installed the fglrx driver from AMD.

Comment: I tried all 3 suggestions of additional drivers that ubuntu gave me to choose from, and tried to install the drivers from AMD's web page `.run` file. But when I tried to install that it said that they won't fit for my graphics card or something like that. I guess fglrx is that `.run` file right? I did all these stuff the last 2days and I'm sleepless because of this problem. Sorry that my information aren't so clear.

Comment: Have a look here http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Features#Switchable_Graphic_Chips_Status

Comment: I did and I'm not sure how that will help me, I'm willing to not use my full hardware capabilities IF I can at lest use my hardware with ubuntu, that's how desperate I am. But how can I make things work? (Still asking cause I'm still creating a bootable stick to install ubuntu again and try Leopoldo's link)

Comment: @Manuel I just tried again to install amd's drivers it said that my graphics card is not supported by that driver and that install will not proceed. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: @Leopoldo Pla, in the link that you gave me... My process stop right where it says check if your graphics card is supported... mine is not.

Comment: @Deus Deceit: According to the release notes the device ist not supported (only up to 7xxxx (http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/amdcatalyst13-4linreleasenotes.aspx)), and Ubuntu 12.10 is the official supported version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the beta driver of this month following the tutorial of this answer:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513)

Beta Driver: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-6-beta-x86.x86_64.zip

I suggest to try with the beta driver because the changelog says that adds support your graphic card: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-6LINBetaDriver.aspx

Comment: Obviously they are not stable, but is better than one that doesn't support your graphic card. At the end of the month I expect to have the stable driver of 13.6.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but changelog doesn't mention my graphics card. Damn it and I was about to become happy. I guess I'll have to wait. Weird thing is that the first time I looked, I could swear it was in it. Then AFTER I re-installed ubuntu and downloaded the drivers, I got the `Your card is not supported message`. Then I look at the changelog again... and my card wasn't there indeed. :S

Comment: That's true, the 8730M is not supported yet. Well, you can try with the opensource ones that are enabled by default when you install Ubuntu.

Comment: No luck with that either, I tried that on my first install, it gave me 3 choices, I tried them all, no luck. Thanks for your effort tho, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I marked this one as an answer because AMD released drivers that support my graphics card. So this answer can be a "hint" for others to look at amd's website.

Answer (score 0):

To have the very latest AMD drivers, you should try the worg-edgers PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

It solved the same kind of problem on one of my Ubuntu 12.04 workstation.

Comment: I installed the package for ati drivers (not from edgers tho, normal ones) from that site already and what i got was boot failure. The laptop was booting and stayed at black blank screen. Had to re-install to try the rest of choices. Do you have the same graphics card or same series? Cause from what I found out so far, there's no driver for my graphics card.

Comment: did you download the driver from amd website?

Comment: You mean when I tried to install the drivers from the site you posted? If I had ati drivers already installed? If yes, the answer is no, I did that on a fresh install. If that's not what you mean then: I tried the drivers from amd website, beta and released ones, they didn't work, I tried the drivers that ubuntu offer from scratch, no effect either. I just don't think my card will function at the moment. I have to wait for the drivers i guess.

Comment: but did you add the PPA to your list of repositories?

Comment: Yup, added the PPA. For now I'm still using the onboard graphics card of my laptop, thank god it's there.