# Can't Use Radeon 8790M on Latitude E6540 with Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, fglrx

Trying to use the Radeon 8790M on my Dell Latitude E6540 running Kubuntu 13.04 (Raring). This laptop also has an Intel adapter (for power saving). lspci gives:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Mars [Radeon HD 8790M]
```

Tried using the standard fglrx and fglrx-update and aticonfig results in (in a message box):

```
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

Trying AMD's drivers always renders the same result:

```
Your graphics adaper is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed.
```

There is no 3D acceleration, as evident by running glxgears:

```
$ glxgears 
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  12
Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

This may be an issue of the multi-adapter situation, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for asking this Stanga, if this isn't resolved, do you know if the radeon can be disabled fully in linux and have any external displays still work? Also, how is the power usage in powertop with the radeon off?

Comment: Doesn't look good. As far as i understand the Radeon isn't active, though probably not fully disabled. I found no way to effect this situation.

I'm not even sure whether the latest driver (3.8) does not recognize the adapter because the driver is broken (it is beta) or because the Radeon is switched away in favor of the Intel. 

Anyway, external screen works fine, and power consumption is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed patience was the solution.

ATI just published an updated driver ([13.8 beta2](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-8LINBetaDriver.aspx)), which installs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have installed AMD Catalyst™ 13.4 Proprietary Linux Graphics Driver. Read the [Release Notes for Catalyst™ 13.4](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/amdcatalyst13-4linreleasenotes.aspx). It does not support the AMD Radeon 8000 series. May be you should try installing [AMD Catalyst™ 13.8 LINUX Beta Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-8LINBetaDriver.aspx). It supports 8000 series according to the link. Warning: 13.8 is still in beta stage.

Comment: Thanks yash. Tried 13.4, the beta and an older version. All resulted in the same `Your graphics adaper is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed.`

Comment: May be you should wait for the Official 13.8 release. Its a bummer, I know. Similar thing happened to me way back when HD5000 series was new and AMD's website still hadn't released supporting drivers. If you haven't tried `Section 2.1. Installing via command line` from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI), give it a shot. It will install the most appropriate drivers. Don't forget `sudo apt-get update` before you start installing via command line.

Comment: [This user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303484/problem-with-amd-hd-8xxx-series-graphics-card?rq=1) has similar problems. You might want to go through for some suggestions.